# Back button ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, decorator, back

I'm have a project in rails, when i need to add more add button it just refer to index.

I have a view like this.

```
<% if decorator_class.show_back_button? && !(defined?(omit_button_to_index) && omit_button_to_index) %>
    <%= link_to icon_tag('back', _('Back')), action: :index %>
  <% end %>
```

And i use this in my decorator

```
def self.show_back_button?
    is_admin_or_publisher_or_sub_publishers?
  end
```

When i click the button, its always back to index list, i just need to refer preveous page, i dont how to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%= link_to icon_tag('back', _('Back')), :back %>
```

Comment: it's work, but only prev once, i have content-sub content-deep content
when i'm in deep content, its only back to sub content, it can't back to content..any conlusion bout this? @santosh

Answer (score 0):

I already solve this issues by make new view.

```
<%= link_to icon_tag('back', _('Back')), controller: 'prev_page', action: 'show', id: @record.prev_page_id %>
```